# Soyuz 16 ASTP rehearsal for Apollo Soyuz - Diagram required

Tags: soyuz-spacecraft, reference-request, docking-port, apollo-soyuz

I recall that I saw a diagram of Soyuz 16 (the full ASTP rehearsal performed by Filiptchenko and Rukavishinikov in late 1974) made by Schliadinsky in a magazine. It featured the docking ring simulator. I never saw another drawing, nor a actual flight hardware photo of Soyuz 16 and its docking ring simulator. Does anyone have something on this subject?

The photo is from Soyuz 19 in assembly shop and the rendering is my view of Soyuz 16.

[image: Soyuz 19 (ASTP) on MIK assembly hall]

[image: My 3D rendering of Soyuz 16]

Comment: So what is your actual question? I can't understand it, quite honestly.

Answer (score 2):

All of the authoratitive information about the apollo-soyuz project can be found in the official NASA [history documents](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-4209/toc.htm).

Are these what you are looking for?

[image: Illustration of mockups of docking mechanism]

(I do note that some of the schematic diagrams have been elided from that history document, but are probably still in the print version.)

Comment: No. Soyuz 16 carried a special docking ring to simulate the Apollo ASTP hardware. These photos shows test models of Apollo APAS 75 hardware, not the simulator ring carried by Soyuz 16. What I want (and I think I was clear) is a photo of the actual Soyuz 16 docking simulator - as I show in my rendering.